# How to add a dynamic class to body tag in Gatsby.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Obviously, that's not an easy task, as the only thing that changes in the `html.js` template file by default are the head meta tags and the content.

The meta tags are handled by the Helmet component (`{head.title.toComponent()}` and `{head.meta.toComponent()}`) and the HTML changes inside the template are managed by React. (`<div id="react-mount" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }} />`)

The body tag however is outside the scope of React, which is why I can't figure out how to change it on-the-fly when I navigate from page to page. That's exactly what I'd need though as I wanna apply a different body background to each page.

I know that I could solve this by using the `exports.onRouteUpdate` in `gatsby-browser.js`, but I would like the class to be present even if JS is disabled in the browser. Means I'd like it to be there even if I export without the `bundle.js` file, just generating the static site HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does look like react-helmet supports dynamically/statically setting a class on the `<html>` element.

They don't want to support setting classes on the body though... https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/182

If you really need to support body classes, then this module does something very similar to react-helmet but for body classes https://github.com/iest/react-body-classname

Comment: This is at least not true anymore, you can add a class to the body with helmet via `bodyAttributes`

Comment: Does facebook read metadata **dynamically** added with gatsby-helmet ? Or will I have to use SSR? e.g. a product details page will show different products all with their own metadata dynamically injected into <head> tag

Answer (score 72):

React-helmet now supports adding attributes to body element as well.

So, if you want to add a class to a specific component/page, you can do something like this:

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

// Inside your component
<Helmet
    bodyAttributes={{
        class: 'new-class-for-body'
    }}
/>

// or

<Helmet>
    <body className="new-class-for-body" />
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Thank you! It did solved the issue in my case.

I just had to `yarn upgrade react-helmet && yarn start` and then I saw the class applied to the body element.

Answer (score 8):

**February 2023**:

Since the release of `gatsby@5.5.0`, the preferred way of doing this is using the [Gatsby Head API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/). (The `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` plugin has been [deprecated](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/#%EF%B8%8F-this-package-will-be-deprecated).)

In your page file, export a `<Head>` component with a `<body className />` element inside:

```
export const Head = () => <body className="your-class-name" />
```

You can also do this alongside other `<Head>` changes, e.g.:

```
export const Head = () => (
  <>
    <html lang="en" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello World" />
    <body className="home-page" />
  </>
)
```